# MassTransit not working with existing RabbitMQ exchange and queue

Tags: masstransit

Below is how I have configured Mass Transit in the program.cs of the producer

```
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x => 
{
    EndpointConvention.Map<IndexMessage>(new Uri($"queue:QueueRequest"));
    x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host("localhost", "/", h =>
        {
            h.Username("guest");
            h.Password("guest");
        });
    });
});
```

QueueRequest is an existing exchange binded to exiting queue QueueRequest (which has TTL and DeadLetter exchange set).

Then I use Ibus instanse to send.

```
await _bus.Send<IndexMessage>(indexMessage);
```

I am missing something when configuring mass transit. Do I have to configure receive endpoint? Please note I have separate service for producer and consumer.

Comment: I changed the config to map to exchange instead of queue and it's working now. EndpointConvention.Map<IndexMessage>(new Uri($"exchange:QueueRequest"));